# Change value(variable) in URL after adding URL

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a URL with variables, and I need to change variables after initiating URL
for example

```
key = ""
secret = ""
url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/data?key={key}&secret={secret}".format(key=key, secret=secret)
key= "bbb"
print(url)
```

but I get a blank result, only works when I add value before initiating the URL

<<<http://127.0.0.1:5000/data?key=&secret=

Comment: you should declare key before the url

Comment: format returns a formatted string, not some sort of context aware data structure. if you change values you will have to call format again(on the original string!)

Comment: Yes, this is how variables work in Python…

Comment: thanks, some short example will be useful :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can have two variables, one to store the unformatted string `http://127.0.0.1:5000/data?key={key}&secret={secret}` ( `url_template` in the below code) and one to store the result of the url once the value of `key` (`url` in the below code) is obtained

```
key = ""
secret = ""
url_unformatted = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/data?key={key}&secret={secret}"
key= "bbb"
url = url_unformatted.format(secret=secret, key=key)
print(url)
```